# Ice-cream seller on a beach, continuation)

Tags: economics

Unlike the problem from the trainer version, here the locations of the sellers are fixed but the prices are not. Suppose that a beach is a segment of length l and is uniformly occupied by bathers who wish to buy an ice-cream. The pleasure from eating an ice-cream is 10, the cost of walking a unit length towards the seller 1 ( the reversal walk is included). Additional ice-cream do not add pleasure. The sellers are situated on the edges of the segment and offer prices $p_1$ and $p_2$ ( in the units of pleasure). A bather compares total utility from buying an ice-cream at either seller and either chooses one of the sellers or stays at his place. The marginal costs of producing an ice-cream for the sellers are zero.

1. write down the utilities of a bather buying an ice-cream at each location. What areas buy ice-cream at the first seller? Second seller?Nowhere?
2. (Monopoly) suppose that $l=40$. what prices will the sellers offer?
3. (Competition) Suppose that $ l=3$. What prices will the sellers offer now?
4. Suppose that $l=9$. What prices will the sellers offer now? Is it possible that one of the sellers offers high monopoly prices instead of competing with the other seller?

Could u please hint me what should I do for that?

Comment: What issues do you have doing (a)? Can you write down your results in your question?

Comment: I don't know how can I start?!!

Comment: I posted an answer for you with a hint. Can you use that to move forward? Feel free to change your question or post comments to the answer with your work if you need further guidance.

Comment: Please don't copy / paste homework questions.

Comment: It is not homework. It is sample of exam problems.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Note that if the bather has to walk more than $10$, he will never buy the ice cream, even for free, since walking is too much trouble.

To make this more formal, a bather at location $x$ has to walk $x$ to the first location (and $\ell - x$ to the second), so his utility must be:

- $10$ for eating the ice cream
- $x$ for walking
- $p_1$ for paying

What is the total utility? What is the same bather's utility for buying at the second location?

Comment: We don't have the total utility. Our assumption those I wrote them.

Comment: @MehdiGolafshan Of course you don't have it. But given what is in the hint, can you combine the components of total utility to actually write down the expression for it?

Comment: I asked from my friend, he told me u can do like this:

first of all we should for every point $x$ of the segment find
1) total pleasure if a person from point $x$ goes to the first end of the segment
(this is $10 - p_1$ - distance to the end)
2) the same for going to the second end
3) compare these numbers, and zero